# xml layout definition in android 1.5

Tags: android

In my application I am using a tabactivity. In tab content area I am using multiple views. Some of the views are created by java code and some of them are created using XML. This works fine in android 1.1, but when i move to android1.5 the layouts which are created using xml cause the problem. In ddms/logcat am getting stack overflow error. What do I have to change to move to ANDROID1.5?

Comment: when i try to add a date picker inside tab activity(even only date picker) it shows error in android1.5.it shows froced close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the StackOverflowError seems to be coming from deep inside Android's code for drawing your UI, your UI is too complicated.

http://androidguys.com/?p=4688

Comment: if we create the layouts using java code ,it may create the same problem or not?

Comment: Yes, it will have the same problem. The issue is not whether you use Java or XML, it is having too deep of a stack of View objects. See the blog post linked to above for details.